# How to render text in monospace SDL2 TTF

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to draw/highlight text in SDL2, there is the simple `SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, text, size);` and then `SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);`, and then `query` the texture, and then draw the text, but this text adapts to kerning and is not all the same size (widths and heights). In doing so, I can't figure out how to do highlighting due to the changing size in characters. How can I draw/render text in monospace such that each character is the same width (for example, default codeblocks text editor spaces text in monospace)?

Comment: The easiest option is to use a monospace font.

Comment: Yes, I just mean something like arial.ttf for example

Comment: Then, render individual glyphs (letters) and space them as you want.

Comment: I tried this, but to draw a bunch of text I have to iterate through the lengths of text and it runs far slower. Is there no way to use a font like ```arial.ttf``` and create a monospace texture of text?

Comment: I don't get it, why iterate through text lengths? Render all the glyphs you need to surfaces, then draw the surfaces with the spacing you want. This doesn't require querying text length. Or, if you want to, draw glyphs from those surfaces to a single surface first.

Comment: If im doing them by individual letters, when I call SDL_RenderCopy(), i need to draw a character. So by drawing a word, say "Text", that word will now require 4 iterations of drawing, rather than 1 if it were a texture

Comment: Yep. If that's too slow, draw them to a single large surface first, then draw that surface

Comment: ohhhh. You can do that?? How?

Comment: Use https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface